# "dialyzer: Analysis failed with error.." (dialyzer bug? or wrong use of map-type?)

Tags: elixir, dialyzer

Working on a very simple application in my progress of learning elixir, I ran into a minor roadblock when checking the types with dialyzer. Running dialyzer on my code results in an `Analysis failed` error... So far dialyzer has only given me *warnings* and not *errors* when I violate the type spec's, so I have no clue what the error is about.

Trying to narrow down the problem, I made an ultra simple function which performs the offending return value.

```
  @spec blabla(integer) :: %{atom => any}
  def blabla(1) do
    %{:error => 'wrong input (US-state)'}
  end
  def blabla(2) do
    %{ location: 'New York City, Central Park, NY', temp_c: '23.3',
       visibility_mi: '10.00', weather: 'A Few Clouds', wind_dir: 'North',
       wind_kt: '0' }
  end
```

When running dialyzer on this I get following error

```
  Proceeding with analysis...
=ERROR REPORT==== 14-Jul-2015::17:26:55 ===
Error in process <0.31.0> with exit value: {function_clause,[{erl_types,t_form_to_string,[{type,12,map_field_assoc,{type,12,atom,[]},{type,12,any,[]}}],[{file,"erl_types.erl"},{line,4546}]},{erl_types,t_form_to_string_list,2,[{file,"erl_types.erl"},{line,4637}]},{erl_types,t_form_to_string... 


dialyzer: Analysis failed with error:
{function_clause,[{erl_types,t_form_to_string,
                             [{type,12,map_field_assoc,
                                    {type,12,atom,[]},
                                    {type,12,any,[]}}],
                             [{file,"erl_types.erl"},{line,4546}]},
                  {erl_types,t_form_to_string_list,2,
                             [{file,"erl_types.erl"},{line,4637}]},
                  {erl_types,t_form_to_string,1,
                             [{file,"erl_types.erl"},{line,4634}]},
                  {erl_types,t_form_to_string,1,
                             [{file,"erl_types.erl"},{line,4590}]},
                  {dialyzer_contracts,contract_to_string_1,1,
                                      [{file,"dialyzer_contracts.erl"},
                                       {line,107}]},
                  {dialyzer_contracts,extra_contract_warning,6,
                                      [{file,"dialyzer_contracts.erl"},
                                       {line,712}]},
                  {dialyzer_contracts,picky_contract_check,7,
                                      [{file,"dialyzer_contracts.erl"},
                                       {line,686}]},
                  {dialyzer_contracts,get_invalid_contract_warnings_funs,5,
                                      [{file,"dialyzer_contracts.erl"},
                                       {line,654}]}]}
```

**Am I defining the map-type in a wrong way? or is this some bug in dialyzer?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code or the typespec. Looks like a dialyzer bug, you can try updating to the latest version of Erlang.

Comment: thanks, upgrading from erlang OTP 17 to 18 seemed to help